# Angular2 want to upload to S3

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to multipart upload using Angular 2.
I wrote the following code.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

@Component({

})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

    progress: Array<any> = []
    file: any

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    uploadfile(event) {
        AWS.config.accessKeyId = '';
        AWS.config.secretAccessKey = '';
        AWS.config.region = ''
        let bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: ''}});
        let params = {Key: this.file.name, Body: this.file, ContentType: this.file.type};
        bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            console.log(err, data);
        });
    }

    fileEvent(event: any){
        let files = event.target.files
        let file = files[0]
        this.file = file
        console.log(this.file)
    }
}
```

I got an error.

```
 Argument of type '{ Key: any; Body: any; ContentType: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PutObjectRequest'.
  Property 'Bucket' is missing in type '{ Key: any; Body: any; ContentType: any; }'.)
```

Please help me.
I would like advice.

I tried to obtain information, but I could not get the correct answer.

Comment: can you check with this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property ? Because the object you are passing seems to be different then whatever is passed to `upload`

Comment: @sandyJoshi Thank you!!! I was silly.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) The object you are passing seems to be different then whatever is expected to be passed to `upload` function.

Answer (score 0):

let params = {Key: this.file.name, Body: this.file, ContentType: this.file.type};

// just change your above line

var params = { Bucket: 'your-bucket-name', Key: this.file.name, Body: this.file,ContentType: this.file.type };